# Undefined method update when updating a record in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble parsing through a hash and then saving certain parts to my database. I'm able to iterate through it to get to the information that I need. My problem is updating the record in my database. I'm trying to update an existing record in my database based on if the country code for each country matches the country code in the XML parse.

In my controller I have:

```
class CountriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @countries = Country.all

    travel_alerts = request_data('http://travel.state.gov/_res/rss/TAs.xml')
    travel_warnings = request_data('http://travel.state.gov/_res/rss/TWs.xml')

    # Sets warnings
    warnings_array = travel_warnings["rss"]["channel"]["item"]
    warnings_array.each do |warning|
      @country = Country.find_by(code: warning["identifier"].strip)
      @country.update(title: warning["title"], 
                      description: warning["description"])
    end
  end
end

...
```

I've tried using .update and .save, but neither works. When I try update I get:

```
undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass
```

Does the update method need to be explicitly defined in the Country model? If so, what's the best way to have access to the parsed information since that's being done in the controller?

Comment: This just means that `Country.find_by(code: warning["identifier"].strip)` didn't find anything, so `@country` would be Nil, and Nil has no update method. You may want to verify that `@country` is not Nil before trying to update ex. `unless @country.nil? @country.update(etc...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It raises an error, because `Country` by given code was not found, then `find_by` returns `nil`, on which update method does not exist.

Instead of `find_by` executrun `find_by!` - you should get `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error`

If it is expected some countries do not exist put your update statement within if block

```
if @country
  @country.update ... 
end
```

Comment: Great, thank you!! Enclosing it within an update statement worked (was driving me crazy trying to figure it out). Appreciate the help!